# Mount Linux NFS share on Mountain Lion 10.8.5

Tags: macos, mount, automount, nfs

I am new to using Apple as main OS. I am used to fstab in Linux to keep the mounts for nfs. When I use `Go to` in Finder to mount `nfs://serveripaddress/home/shared` I get a permissions error.

The below command works from Terminal though:

```
    mount -t nfs -o resvport,nolocks,locallocks,intr,soft,wsize=32768,rsize=3276 \
        serveripaddress:/home/shared /private/shared
```

How can I get this to be mounted each time I log in and vpn to the network where this share resides?

Comment: Currently I have resorted to a shell script in my documents folder that when run will mount the desired drives.

Comment: I am also grappling with NFS - see my answer to your question below. Could you please explain the mount options in your example and why you're using them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have spent quite a bit of time figuring out automounts of NFS shares in OS X...

Somewhere along the line, Apple decided allowing mounts directly into /Volumes should not be possible:

/etc/auto_master **(see last line)**:

```
#
# Automounter master map
#
+auto_master        # Use directory service
/net            -hosts      -nobrowse,hidefromfinder,nosuid
/home           auto_home   -nobrowse,hidefromfinder
/Network/Servers    -fstab
/-          -static
/-          auto_nfs    -nobrowse,nosuid
```

/etc/auto_nfs **(this is all one line)**:

```
/Volumes/my_mount    -fstype=nfs,noowners,nolockd,noresvport,hard,bg,intr,rw,tcp,nfc nfs://192.168.1.1:/exports/my_share
```

This will not work (anymore!) though it "should".

```
$ sudo automount -cv
...
automount: /Volumes/my_mount: mountpoint unavailable
```

### What's the solution?

It's so easy my jaw dropped when I figured it out.
Basically, we trick OS X into thinking we're mounting * somewhere else. *

When you're talking about paths in just about any environment, the root folder is the highest path you can reach, whether it's `C:\` (windows) or `/` (*nix)

When you're at this path, attempting to reach the parent path, via `..` will keep you at the root path.

For example: `/../../../../` is still just `/`

By now, a few of you have already figured it out.

### TL;DR / Solution:

Change your `/etc/auto_nfs` config from **(this is all one line)**:

```
/Volumes/my_mount    -fstype=nfs,noowners,nolockd,noresvport,hard,bg,intr,rw,tcp,nfc nfs://192.168.1.1:/exports/my_share
```

To **(this is all one line)**:

```
/../Volumes/my_mount    -fstype=nfs,noowners,nolockd,noresvport,hard,bg,intr,rw,tcp,nfc nfs://192.168.1.1:/exports/my_share
```

And re-run the automounter:

```
$ sudo automount -cv
...
automount: /Volumes/my_mount: mounted
```

..... there you go! Technically `/../Volumes` is still `/Volumes`, but the automounter does not see things that way ;)

This configuration persists the mount across restarts, and creates the mountpoint automatically.

## I KNOW, RIGHT?

Answer (score 0):

I am also new to OSX. This is how I mounted my Linux share. I used `sudo vifs` which is apparently the OSX preferred way to edit `/etc/fstab`. I then entered a mount stanza like the below:

```
myserver:/path/to/files /Users/me/files nfs resvport,bg,async,nfc 0 0
```

This works and the mount happens automatically. However I am suffering from the famous show-performance-in-finder issue (copying to server fast on command line but excruciatingly slow in finder).

The mount options I used are:

- `resvport` - needed to use a low port as expected by Linux server
- `bg` - the mount will be silently retried in the background if unsuccessful
- `async` - my attempt to increase performace. `man mount_nfs` and read the risks.
- `nfc` - makes UTF-8 characters work properly (`man mount_nfs`)

For completeness, here is the server-side configuration  in `/etc/exports`:

```
/home/me/files 10.20.30.40(rw,sync,all_squash,anonuid=1000,anongid=100)
```

Here, 10.20.30.40 should be the IP of the OSX client (assuming you want to restrict the export to that client). My Linux uid/gid are 1000/100. I've used `all-squash` to convert uid/gid to those I have on Linux because of the OSX differences. This isn't a perfect way to do this but it meets my immediate needs.